# How to rectify the error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I create an one webpage in asp.net all the time i am facing the following pbm how to rectify it..

`if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)`

Comment: This is very unclear.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I voted to close this, because it is really hard to understand what's being asked here.

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or is it a logic problem? You'll get help here, but you'll need to provide some context and a description of what the problem actually is. You're question is currently very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to check that ds.Tables[0] exists first

Answer (score 0):

If you are constantly checking on your pages to see if that dataset has a table with rows, I would think you would want to make some helper class to check that your dataset is not null, and that whatever tables have actual rows.  Also you might want to think about moving these to typed datasets.